# How can I start and view a zoom meeting with python Django and zoom api?

Tags: python, django, zoom-sdk, lms, zoomus

I'm trying to create a LMS system with Django and I need to be able start and view zoom meetings from the website using zoom api. I found a python library called `zoomus` for python to connect to the api but they don't give any documentation. does anyone have an idea how to do this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by zoom API. Follow this link: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api

You will need to get an API key and a secret key from the zoom jwt app and you can proceed with that. Also, remember to check the zoom compliance issues. You can only manage meetings within your own account and you cannot run more than one concurrent meeting.

If everything looks good, you can hit the zoom API with an API key and signed jwt(https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/jwt#generating-jwts) and get the JSON response. Check request and response schema at the zoom api docs.

Comment: I'm will try this. Thank you